# Does the operator `!=` use `==`?

Tags: ruby, comparison, operator-overloading, operators

I defined a class `User`, and overrode its `==` operator like this:

```
class User
  attr_reader :age

  def initialize age
    @age = age
  end

  def ==(other_user)
    return true if @age == other_user.age
    false
  end
end
```

Does the default implementation of `!=` use `==`? Do I not need to override `!=` as well?

Comment: _Sidenote_: `==` is **not an operator**, it is a method, defined on the [in this particular case] `User` class.

Comment: @mudasobwa In fact it is both. `def ==` defines a *method* that is called when the `==` *operator* is used.

Comment: @Stefan well, yes; I meant what is mentioned in the OP is a method, not an operator.

Comment: The [Comparable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html)  gives you `<, <=, ==, >=,  >`, and `between? ` methods in return for a `<=>` method. (`def <=>(other); @age <=> other.age; end`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless any class in the class hierarchy has `!=` overridden, the default implementation on [`BasicObject#!=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-21-3D) will be called.

If you’ll click on “click to toggle source” on the page I linked, you’ll see that the default implementation

```
 VALUE
rb_obj_not_equal(VALUE obj1, VALUE obj2)
{
    VALUE result = rb_funcall(obj1, id_eq, 1, obj2);
    return RTEST(result) ? Qfalse : Qtrue;
}
```

simply calls `==` and negates the returned value.

That said, **while you are certain, that no ancestor of your class overrode the default behaviour of `BasicObject#!=`, it is safe to override `==` only**.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no.

Both `==` and `!=` are methods, thus you can always override them individualy.

```
class X
  def ==(other)
    true
  end

  def !=(other)
    true
  end
end

a = X.new
b = X.new

a == b  #=> true
a != b  #=> true
```

By default, `!=` uses `==`.

Comment: The OP states about the **default** `!=`. The "no" part of your answer and your whole example is irrelevant to the question. And when those parts are removed, the answer is no more informative than mudasobwa's, which was answered earlier.